# Function Menu in OpenText Content Server 10, not working

Tags: menu, opentext, livelink

I have OpenText Content Server 10, but in my Browser when i click on some docs for Function Menu, my CS10 hangs and also the LiveLink Builder Hangs too.

The Function menu is not working, Is there a way i can enable this again.

Comment: First of all, don´t use 64bit browser Second go to http://knowledge.opentext.com and download the latest patches. If it still not working - write (or call) to Opentext customer support.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. CS10 cannot run in the debugging mode together with the Builder. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

add the about:blank to the trusted sites in IE

this should work